# Different coloured circles with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create four different colored circles in CSS.

I already defined the padding size, color, height and background.

This is all very new to me. Could you help me how to get 4 different colored circles (rings) with the same background color?

```css
.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="numberCircle">30</div>
<div class="numberCircle">1</div>
<div class="numberCircle">2</div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: add your code here HTML and CSS. there is many ways to do this. Nobody did propose this yet :) http://jsfiddle.net/dQR9T/6331/ there is shadow too to use

Answer (score 2):

The wording of your question is a bit confusing, but based on the Fiddle you provided, I think this is what you're going for(just change the border color for each circle):

```css
.numberCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    display:inline-block;
}
        .numberCircle:nth-child(1) {
          border: 2px solid blue;
        }
        .numberCircle:nth-child(2) {
          border: 2px solid red;
        }
        .numberCircle:nth-child(3) {
          border: 2px solid green;
        }
        .numberCircle:nth-child(4) {
          border: 2px solid yellow;
        }
```

```html
<div class="numberCircle"></div>
<div class="numberCircle"></div>
<div class="numberCircle"></div>
<div class="numberCircle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to use border-color to set only the color of the border.

```css
.numberCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */

    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 8px;
    
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    
    font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.red { 
    border-color:red;
}

.blue { 
    border-color:blue;
}

.yellow { 
    border-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="numberCircle red"></div>
<div class="numberCircle blue"></div>
<div class="numberCircle yellow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best is to add an additional class which sets the color of each individual ring

Like this:

```
<div class="numberCircle red">30</div>
<div class="numberCircle blue">1</div>
<div class="numberCircle black">2</div>
<div class="numberCircle yellow">2</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dQR9T/6327/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add an additional class for every circle color like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="numberCircle red-circle">30</div>
<div class="numberCircle blue-circle">1</div>
<div class="numberCircle green-circle">2</div>
```

CSS:

```
.numberCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */

    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 8px;

    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;

    font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.blue-circle {
  border-color: blue;
}

.green-circle {
  border-color: green;
}

.red-circle {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dQR9T/6328/

I hope this answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, that's what you want:

```
.numberCircle:nth-child(1) { border: 2px solid blue; }
.numberCircle:nth-child(2) { border: 2px solid green; }
.numberCircle:nth-child(3) { border: 2px solid yellow; }
.numberCircle:nth-child(4) { border: 2px solid red; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dQR9T/6329/)